# solr - Size of Heap Space

Tags: solr, alfresco, alfresco-search-services

I have an Alfresco 6.2.0 instance on an Ubuntu system using solr specification 6.6.7 and Search Services 1.4.0. I have two cores with currently 155364 documents in the alfresco core and 126054 documents in the archive core. Until today solr hat 1 GB heap space and the last few weeks problems where rising that solr exits with heap space out of memory. Today I raised to 2 Gb, hoping that this is enough.

Is this normal, that solr needs this amount of memory? Are 100.000 documents (no big files excepted the images) really so many, that solr needs more than 1GB? I am just wondering, because the instance is used by a small company.

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-2 GB heap is not much for Solr, but it is little. In fact, it is the component in the Alfresco architecture that is usually allocated the most memory. The index with the metadata for the full text should fit into th memory if possible to ensure fast searching. You can have a look at [Sizing my Alfresco Search Services](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-blog/sizing-my-alfresco-search-services/ba-p/294052).